# Wso2 API Manager : Different API Endpoint port for each Tenant

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I know we can change offset to change port for wso2 api manager. But that changes overall system port. I have a particular requirement to configure wso2 api manager in which Each Tenant will have a different ports for execution. By default all tenant along with carbons.super is running on 8243 and 8280 ports. is there a way to change it for tenant ? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can open new ports by copy-pasting below sections in `axis2.xml` and changing just the port. But you can't restrict them by tenants.

```
<transportReceiver name="http" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpListener">
```

---

```
<transportReceiver name="https" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLListener">
```

Comment: Thanks Bhathiya. I have requirement in hand which says one tenant's api should not be accessible from regular ports 8243/8280.  I am assuming after adding new ports all tenant's api will be available on both new port and old port ?

Comment: I can suggest a hacky way to get this done, but the best solution would be to use a reverse proxy in front of APIM, with rules you need.

Comment: Yes, Reverse proxy can block / allow traffic based api context /t/tenant.com. We are discussing that. But client/tenant wants a solution close to API manager so that any issues with reverse proxies do not expose them... please suggest your hacky way we will try to evaluate whether or not we need both? Thank you !

Comment: Hi Bhathiya, please advise on how to configure